установка blackarch linux, столкнулся с ошибкой package manager error
извиняюсь что вопрос не по теме, но может кто знает как решить данную проблему, ставлю blackarch linux slim 2023.05 на основу с целью изучения системы но при графической установке столкнулся с ошибкой в конце установки после 35% выводит ошибку Package manager error, пробовал уже всё, менял зеркала, пробовал на разных устройствах, интернет стабильный но все равно ничего не помогает, ответ не могу нигде найти помогите пожалуйста кто понимает в чем ошибка. Код ошибки the package manager could not prepare updates. The command <pre>pacman</pre> returned error code 1

returned error code 1 для pacman может означать всё что угодно. Графические установщики для подобных дистрибутивов это скорее подспорье тем кто уже в курсе что да как и призвано сократить время установки, для новичка же в этом деле лучше всего начать с ручной установки что позволит понять(возможно не с первого раза) процесс установки а также локализовать возникшую/допущенную ошибку так как сам процесс разбит на мелкие этапы. Попробуйте в ручную установить тот же Арч возможно поймёте где ошибка, blackarch можно после уже накатить сверху

понял, спасибо, простой арч я уже ставил как раз таки без графического интерфейса а только командами, а также у меня получилось поставить blackarch full так как он ставится тоже без графического интерфейса, он поставился без проблем но мне нужен был конкретно слим так как в версии фулл полно ненужных мне инструментов которые занимают много памяти и нету нормального окружения рабочего стола, второе более проблемное, так как не получалось поставить какой нибудь xfce иначе слим бы и не нужен был

как вариант, можно просто установить тот же Ctlos (это чистый арч с довольно минимальной кастомизацией), и уже к нему подключить репу от blackarch - Установка поверх ArchLinux, ну а после уже установить только нужные пакеты/программы из подключённой репы. По итогу получаем минимум мороки и максимальный профит.

мне в целом нравится ещё вид как выглядит блэкарч, можно ли хотя бы примерно привести ее к такому же виду, окна, sddm и т.д

конфиги программ и оболочек есть в официальной репе блэкарча на гитхабе
